# Html page in cache

Tags: php, html, caching

Im working on a one page website and I need to use a lots of photos (72) / carousel (3 with 12 photos each) . The website is of course really laggy and slow so I've been told to use the cache system. The thing is, I would like to know if there's an easy way to put the whole page into the cache and if so how to do it, and if not, what's the best way to improve the website without having to touch the photos.
Thank you.

Comment: this had good info https://varvy.com/pagespeed/cache-control.html and make sure that you optimize the images!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see how this is off topic. HINT: Post code and effort

Comment: In-memory, server-side caching (e.g. REDIS) isn't going to help (appreciably) - and client-side browser caching will be happening anyway (for most people); in essence, caching isn't the answer to this problem.

Comment: The main problem is that the 2nd and 3rd carousel doesn't work (cant swipe photos) and when you scroll through the page its not smooth at all, so yeah I don't know if its server sided of client sided

Answer (score 1):

You can use [link prefetching](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Link_prefetching_FAQ). This tells the browser to download content in the background when there is bandwidth available. For example:

```
<link rel="prefetch" href="/images/big.jpeg">
```

Notice that this is different from the typical image link

```
<img src="/images/big.jpeg">
```

The browser will first fetch what is necessary to load the current view. Then when it's done it will start pre-fetching what you marked as `<link rel="prefetch"...`

There are space limits to consider though, and they vary from browser to browser so be sure to test. For instance, rather than try to prefetch all photos, you may just want to prefetch the photos of the current carousel.

Comment: Thanks, im looking into it, I think I will try it as soon as I can when I get home.

Answer (score 0):

First optimize the size of your photos if you haven't http://compressjpeg.com/ (it works for both, jpeg and png).

The browser usually have a cache system you don't have to worry about, but if you must, there is always an option to store the pics on a temporary folder.

http://www.phpfastcache.com/ this is a simple and good option to solve your problems

Comment: phpFastCache looks interesting. I had never heard of it.  However I'm not sure server-side caching is the solution. The lag the OP's users experience is probably not because the server is too slow to read images from disk, but because the network traffic is too slow.  For this problem, caching images in server memory will not speed things up, but will only cause the cache process to consume a lot of resources.

Comment: Oh yeah I forgot to optimize the photos and phpfastcache.com looks cool, I'll try it when I get hom too.

Comment: I wouldn't cache the images server side either, it is just an option, the trick @beetlejuice posted is pretty good.. that, optimizing the pictures size and the native browser cache (after the first visit ofc), would do the trick quite nicely.